# Send Ajax call to action but how to convert given string data to something usable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tablednd

I am using tableDnD to drag and drop rows in a table, after the rows have been dropped i want an updated list of data to tell me the new order of the rows.  I want this data sent back up to the action via AJAX.

this is my function and ajax call

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#profileTable').tableDnD({
            onDrop: function(table, row) {
                var rows1 = table.tBodies[0].rows;
                $.ajax('@(Url.Action("SaveTopTenGames"))',
                    {
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache:false,
                        data: {json:$.tableDnD.serialize()},
                        success:function(st){

                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

            }
        });
    });
```

and this is currently the string data im receiving in my action

```
"profileTable%5B%5D=1&profileTable%5B%5D=2&profileTable%5B%5D=4&profileTable%5B%5D=5&profileTable%5B%5D=3&profileTable%5B%5D=6&profileTable%5B%5D=7&profileTable%5B%5D=8&profileTable%5B%5D=9&profileTable%5B%5D=10"
```

Now I have no idea how to convert that string into anything I can use. Any suggestion on what I should do ?

Comment: @imGerg: Will you post `tableDnD` as json, is it mvc2/mvc3/mvc4?

Comment: im using mvc4, i dont care what im sending back as long as its something i can use to say oh number 1 moved to position 2 and number 2 is now number 1 so i can update the database

Comment: @imGerg Your action mustbe something look like this `SaveTopTenGames(string json)` because i've tried tableDnD and when i drag or drop and gets string like this `table-1[]=2&table-1[]=1&table-1[]=4&table-1[]=3&table-1[]=5&table-1[]=6`

Comment: yea at the moment that is what it looks like but i dont know how to take that data and put it into a collection so i can use it.  Also,i have no idea where the %5s are coming from either

Comment: okay i figured that the %5B = [ and %5D = ] now in the action how do i convert that string into a collection?

Comment: What do you mean by `Collection`, like Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the json string and split it into Array then try This:

```
string json = "profileTable%5B%5D=1&profileTable%5B%5D=2&profileTable%5B%5D=4&profileTable%5B%5D=5&profileTable%5B%5D=3&profileTable%5B%5D=6&profileTable%5B%5D=7&profileTable%5B%5D=8&profileTable%5B%5D=9&profileTable%5B%5D=10";
var str = json.Replace("%5B", "[").Replace("%5D", "]");
var strArray = str.Split('&');

for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Count(); i++)
{
    //get the required value from strArray
    //Console.WriteLine(strArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ;-)

```
function queryParams(string, separator) {
  var match = $.trim(string || '').match(/([^?#]*)(#.*)?$/);
  if (!match) return {};
  var array = match[1].split(separator || '&'), hash = {}, pair;
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; ++i) {
    pair = array[i];
    if ((pair = pair.split('='))[0]) {
      var key = decodeURIComponent(pair.shift()),
          value = pair.length > 1 ? pair.join('=') : pair[0];
      if (value != undefined) value = decodeURIComponent(value);
      if (key in hash) {
        if (!$.isArray(hash[key])) hash[key] = [hash[key]];
        hash[key].push(value);
      }
      else hash[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return hash;
}

// Will return a hash: { 'profileTable[]': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'] }
queryParams('profileTable%5B%5D=1&profileTable%5B%5D=2&profileTable%5B%5D=4&profileTable%5B%5D=5&profileTable%5B%5D=3&profileTable%5B%5D=6&profileTable%5B%5D=7&profileTable%5B%5D=8&profileTable%5B%5D=9&profileTable%5B%5D=10');
```

Comment: I am getting this error in the console

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCollection> has no method 'trim' `

Comment: I'm using chrome.  When the string is sent through your method the hash comes out like this `B: Array[10]
0: undefined
1: undefined
2: undefined
3: undefined
4: undefined
5: undefined
6: undefined
7: undefined
8: undefined
9: undefined
length: 10
__proto__: Array[0]
D: Array[10]
0: "1&profileTable"
1: "2&profileTable"
2: "5&profileTable"
3: "7&profileTable"
4: "3&profileTable"
5: "4&profileTable"
6: "8&profileTable"
7: "6&profileTable"
8: "9&profileTable"
9: "10"
length: 10`

I put this into your method 
`queryParams($.tableDnD.serialize(),'%5') `